# Create ReSharper live template for comments

Tags: templates, resharper

I'd like to create a ReSharper template that can only be used within comments in my code, but I'm not sure how to do that.

The template I'm creating is a simple one. It allows me to insert the name of the current user and today's date. This is very useful for putting a signature on comments (especially todos).

The live template looks like this:

```
$name$ $date$
```

The template works fine, but ReSharper allows me to use it *anywhere* within my code file. Ideally, I'd like to use it only within a comment block.

I see that ReSharper has options to limit the use of a template to where namespace declarations, type member declarations, query statements, etc. are allowed. Does it have the ability to limit the use of a template to within a comment block? If so, how do I do it?

(Note: I'm using ReSharper 6.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to constrain a template to comments by using the 'Select scopes' functionality provided in ReSharper. It *is*, however, entirely possible to *introduce* such a constraint to the 'Select scopes' window, but that would require writing a small plug-in using the R# SDK. If this is something you'd be interested in doing, I can elaborate further with details.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. If I write a small plug-in for the R# SDK, is there a way to distribute it to the rest of the team using shared settings, or would I have to install it on each developer's workstation?

Comment: At the moment, ReSharper loads the plug-ins either from its local `plugins` directory or the user's `AppData` folder. As a result, it's currently impossible to package up the plug-in together with the project itself. One possibility for your team is to put plugin binaries under source control and then clone them into the necessary folder. That way, you can have a form of centralized updating.

Comment: Hmmm. Given the effort involved, I don't think I'd go that far to get a comment template for ReSharper. But if we eventually have other plugins we'd like to deploy, I might give it a try. Thanks again, Dmitri!